# Javascript framework not working properly same code as jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Simple globe with iTowns</title>
        <style>
            html { height: 100%; }
            body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }
            #viewerDiv { margin: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; }
            canvas { display: block }
        </style>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div id="viewerDiv"></div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/itowns@2.32.0/dist/itowns.js </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('viewerDiv');
            var placement = {
                coord: new itowns.Coordinates('EPSG:4326', 2.351323, 48.856712),
                range: 25000000
            };
            var view = new itowns.GlobeView(viewerDiv, placement);

            var orthoSource = new itowns.WMTSSource({
                url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/3ht7xcw6f7nciopo16etuqp2/geoportail/wmts',
                crs: "EPSG:3857",
                name: 'ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS',
                tileMatrixSet: 'PM',
                format: 'image/jpeg',
            })

            var orthoLayer = new itowns.ColorLayer('Ortho', {
                source: orthoSource,
            });

            view.addLayer(orthoLayer);

            var elevationSource = new itowns.WMTSSource({
                url: 'https://wxs.ign.fr/3ht7xcw6f7nciopo16etuqp2/geoportail/wmts',
                crs: 'EPSG:4326',
                name: 'ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.SRTM3',
                tileMatrixSet: 'WGS84G',
                format: 'image/x-bil;bits=32',
                zoom: {min: 3, max: 10},
            });

            var elevationLayer = new itowns.ElevationLayer('MNT_WORLD', {
                source: elevationSource,
            });

            view.addLayer(elevationLayer);
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

I am using a framework called iTowns and I have copied the code exactly from a jsfiddle they provided as an example. The jsfiddle loads Earth fine but my code does not properly load the land layer and instead I get a blue sphere. I get this error in the console,

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

I am running the website on a live local server. What am I missing here?

http://jsfiddle.net/q70umk6r/

Comment: I don't see the 403 error in the console. Could be because of https. Try using `https` everywhere in `itowns.Fetcher.json()` urls, `itowns.js` in the left panel in resources section and the jsfiddle link itself.

Comment: I just want to make sure, you mean you don't see the 403 error on your own console after copying my code, or your jsfiddle console doesnt have the 403? The jsfiddle is what it should look like but my code does not reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if your resources are available, but given that you're getting a `403`, I'm guessing not.

you could try using cdn package instead though

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/itowns@2.32.0/dist/itowns.js"></script>
```

Comment: This provides the same result.

Answer (score 0):

just because "https://wxs.ign.fr/3ht7xcw6f7nciopo16etuqp2/geoportail/wmts" server dont allow `GET` request that its request headers' `Referer` not "localhost:xx/xxx" or other Registered urls;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).